# Redefining the \printindex command and changing it to a desired form

Tags: macros, indexing

In book class, I want to **redefine** the `\printindex` command and change it to something like the following:

```
‎\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{‎Index}‎‎‎‎
‎\fancypagestyle{plain}{%‎
‎\fancyhf{}‎                        
‎\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}‎
‎\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}‎
}
‎\printindex‎
```

How can I do this?
My tex file is as follow:

```
\documentclass{‎book‎}‎‎
‎\usepackage{fancyhdr} ‎‎
‎\usepackage{makeidx}‎
‎\makeindex‎
‎‎\begin{document}‎‎
‎\tableofcontents‎
‎\chapter{One}‎‎
‎Hi!‎
\index{‎abc‎}
\index{‎def‎}‎‎
‎\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{‎Index}‎‎‎‎
‎\fancypagestyle{plain}{%‎
‎\fancyhf{}‎                        
‎\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}‎
‎\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}‎
}
‎\printindex‎
‎\end{document}
```

Comment: the page style plain is the default for the index. Why do you want to redefine it?

Comment: @Herbert: I wanted to delete the page number on the first page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save a macro away using `\let\origmacro\macro`, where `\origmacro` is a name you can pick. Then your redefine the macro and call its original version internally, mostly at the very end:

```
\let\origprintindex\printindex‎
\renewcommand*{\printindex}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{‎Index}‎‎‎‎%
  ‎\fancypagestyle{plain}{%‎
  ‎  \fancyhf{}‎%
    ‎\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}‎%
    ‎\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}‎%
  }%
  ‎\origprintindex‎
}
```

You might want to place all this into a group.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. BTW, is this method applicable for every command (e.g., ‎\tableofcontents‎)?

Comment: @Vahid: It should work for all user macros. But you must be careful not to redefine a *robust* macro in a *fragile* way. I'm talking about macros which are written *into* to ToC and `.aux` files, e.g. the ones used inside section titles. Also problems arise when two people/packages redefine the same macro and use the same name for '`\origmacro`'.